# How to collect metrics in pg-promise?

Tags: pg-promise

pg-promise internally has a connection pools. When a request is processed, it will

1. fetch a connection from connection pool. if no connection is available, it will wait
2. call db through the connection

I need to collect metrics for times consumed in each step. Is there any way to do that? Can we collect these times at each step and return it to caller?

Comment: See also [Metrics for Postgres connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106343/metrics-for-typeorm-postgres-connection-pool)

Answer (score 0):

There is no timing data related to allocating database connections.

So what you are asking for is not possible.